# How can I log a warning when I "halt()" in Scalatra?

Tags: scala, scalatra

In my Scalatra routes, I often use [`halt()`](http://scalatra.org/guides/2.6/http/routes.html#halting) to fail fast:

```
val user: User = userRepository.getUserById(params("userId"))
    .getOrElse {
        logger.warn(s"Unknown user: $userId")
        halt(404, s"Unknown user: $userId")
    }
```

As shown in the example, I also want to log a warning in those cases. But I'd like to avoid the code duplication between the halt() and the logger. It would be a lot cleaner to simply do:

```
val user: User = userRepository.getUserById(params("userId"))
    .getOrElse(halt(404, s"Unknown user: $userId"))
```

What would be the best way of logging all "HaltExceptions" in a cross-cutting manner ?

I've considered:

1) Overriding the `halt()` method in my route:

```
override def halt[T](status: Integer, body: T, headers: Map[String, String])(implicit evidence$1: Manifest[T]): Nothing = {
    logger.warn(s"Halting with status $status and message: $body")
    super.halt(status, body, headers)
}
```

Aside from the weird method signature, I don't really like this approach, because I could be calling the real `halt()` by mistake instead of the overridden method, for example if I'm halting outside the route. In this case, no warning would be logged.

2) Use `trap()` to log all error responses:

```
trap(400 to 600) {
    logger.warn(s"Error returned with status $status and body ${extractBodyInSomeWay()}")
}
```

But I'm not sure it's the best approach, especially since it adds 201 routes to the `_statusRoutes` Map (one mapping for each integer in the range...). I also don't know how to extract the body here ?

3) Enable some kind of response logging in Jetty for specific status codes ?

---

What would be the best approach to do this? Am I even approaching this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is doing it in a servlet filter like below:

```
package org.scalatra.example

import javax.servlet._
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

class LoggingFilter extends Filter {

  override def init(filterConfig: FilterConfig): Unit = ()
  override def destroy(): Unit = ()

  override def doFilter(request: ServletRequest, response: ServletResponse, chain: FilterChain): Unit = {
    chain.doFilter(request, response)

    val status = response.asInstanceOf[HttpServletResponse].getStatus
    if (status >= 400 && status <= 600) {
      // Do logging here!
    }
  }
}
```

Register this filter in your Bootstrap class (or it's possible even in `web.xml`):

```
package org.scalatra.example

import org.scalatra._
import javax.servlet.ServletContext

class ScalatraBootstrap extends LifeCycle {
  override def init(context: ServletContext): Unit = {
    context.addFilter("loggingFilter", new LoggingFilter())
    context.getFilterRegistration("loggingFilter")
      .addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(classOf[DispatcherType]), true, "/*")

    // mount your servlets or filters
    ...
  }
}
```

In my opinion, Scalatra should provide a way to trap halting easier essentially. In fact, there is a method named `renderHaltException` in `ScalatraBase`, it looks to be possible to add logging by overriding this method at a glance:
https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/blob/cec3f75e3484f2233274b1af900f078eb15c35b1/core/src/main/scala/org/scalatra/ScalatraBase.scala#L512

However we can't do it actually because `HaltException` is package private and it can be accessed inside of `org.scalatra` package only. I wonder `HaltException` should be public.